# What comprises a valid date when using Date.parse in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, json

I have an ASP.NET MVC application running on top of an SQL Server database. On one of the view, a date value is fetched from the database but somehow, `Date.parse` returns `NaN` when I try to parse it into a Date. When I do `console.log`, the date looks like this `2016-03-29T11:54:34.94`. Obviously along the way it was converted from a `DateTime` C# object into its JSON equivalent. Why would JavaScript consider it not to be a valid date yet it came straight from the database?

Comment: Your date is working for me...

Comment: Try doing `var dateTest = newDate('2016-03-29T11:54:34.94');` instead of `Date.parse()`.

Comment: @brso05: That also gives a NaN

Answer (score 1):

if you refer to below link you will notice that in javascript `Date` object there are certain constructor and not all formats of date will create a valid object in javascript across different browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

To be safe I would recommend you to pass an array like `[2016, 3, 29, 12, 0, 0]` to UI and then use javascript as below

```
var dt = new Date(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]);
```

This constructor is supported across all browsers and will give you a valid date